# How can I split a single Metal render output across multiple views?

Tags: gpu, metal, metalkit

I am trying to render using Metal into a set of 100 views in an NSCollectionView (as an example). I am able to render into each view separately, but the setup time of a render for a single view far outweighs the time for a render, and for 100 views at 120Hz I am passing 12000 commandBuffers each containing one render command to the GPU, which is horrendously slow.

An approach I am trying to take to solve this is to render the contents of all 100 views onto a single drawable, and then somehow distribute sections of that drawable across multiple views. I have tried rendering in to one CAMetalLayer and reusing/transforming it, but a layer can only be attached to one view at a time (and I suspected this would be inefficient anyway).

A working example of the naive implementation (writing directly to individual views) can be found here https://github.com/SirWhiteHat/MetalPerformanceProblem

I have explored the following:

[Multiple Render Targets in Metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982547/multiple-render-targets-in-metal) - addresses drawing the same vertices but with different colorAttachments by modifying the fragment shader, but I need to be able to draw different vertices on to different views which is quite different.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/textures/creating_and_sampling_textures - I hoped to find clues as to how to take a rendered texture and split it across views, but this seems to address the opposite; taking a texture and rendering it across a quadrangle to a single view, which still leaves me with "how do I split this across multiple views".

I have also found many examples of ways to draw efficiently into a single view, but not something that can then split my result across multiple views.

This question is a follow-up and clarification with more specificity from my previous question [Rendering into multiple views with Metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77752632/rendering-into-multiple-views-with-metal)

This may actually be more of a Cocoa question (given a finished Metal drawable, how can I distribute its contents across multiple views?), but I suspect that there will be involvement from Metal itself somehow.

Thank you!

Comment: It's more possible on newer machines, but I just don't see how it will be possible to have 100 different live animation views running at 120hz on Intel Macs. I don't think it's a matter of being clever enough, you're just going to hit a hard limit. I don't know enough about your requirements to think of alternative solutions.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock what is it about it being in separate views that precludes it running on older hardware? Older hardware can render all required triangles into one view just fine, what is it about the multiple-view nature that should be so expensive? To be clear, if it runs at 10fps eventually, that’ll be fine for my application, it’s just about how to do it reliably.

Comment: You basically have two options - display in 100 MTKViews (which you've determined is too slow) or render one texture, split into a hundred sub-images and update a hundred views at least 10 times a second. Why do they have to be separate views? Couldn't you render a single view that has a border drawn or something to give the impression they are separate views?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock The latter approach (splitting a texture) is the approach I am trying to explore with this question. Do you know how I could achieve this? They have to be separate views as I am not just tiling the views; instead they form part of an entirely different xib, which is then tiled. The layout in the code example is just that, an example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure splitting it into `UIImages` or `CIImages` that can be displayed in a view is going to be even less efficient than using `MTKViews`. The only thing that comes to mind is signed distance fields used to efficiently render fonts with metal, but that doesn't solve the problem of having a 100 views updated 10 times/sec. https://metalbyexample.com/rendering-text-in-metal-with-signed-distance-fields/

Comment: It seems to me that anything that can be displayed in multiple views could also be displayed in a single view if it's rendered appropriately. Not sure why you have to use a xib or why you can't achieve the same end result.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock It is of course technically possible to build the interface from scratch programmatically and tile it rather than using IB, but that's an awfully long workaround with an awful lot of development time. So far I am yet to see any good reason that presenting multiple small views costs more than one large view, so I'm inclined to assume it's possible and that I'm doing something wrong. If it were shown _why_ it's not possible, that would be different, but all we have is "it's currently slow".

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I still appreciate your engagement with this!

Comment: I mean, you're just saying it sounds like too much work to do things an optimal way. Which is fine, but don't expect the performance you need. The problem is more than one. First you have to split one large texture (after rendering) to 100 separate images, 10 times per second. That is rewriting all the pixels of 1,000 images every second. Then you have to update 100 views - every pixel in every view must be redrawn at 10 times a second - all on the CPU if you're not using MTKView.

Comment: It sounds like an unnecessary effort to do things an entirely different way just because I’ve failed to find the problem in this approach (which _should_ work). So for instance; 1) in terms of splitting the view, I can (and already do) split the view using the GPU, returning 100 separate drawables, trivially and with no CPU overhead. The cost literally only appears when calling drawable.present(), hence this question being asked. And 2) “every pixel 10 times a second”, it has no issue doing it with a single 100x-larger view, so why is 100 smaller views problematic?

Comment: I see no mention of having a 100 separate drawables and no mention of calling drawable.present(). Even worse, you've provided no source code to see how you are actually doing things.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock The link to the source code is in the question. "100 separate drawables" is a natural conclusion of "100 separate views". Regarding calling drawable.present(), this small change has come from rework to try and find the problem; admittedly not updated in the above question but that's because the above question still stands in isolation.

Comment: I assumed the project with "100 separate views" was the same project from your previous question since it was the same link, so I didn't revisit the link. Generally on SO code is posted as part of the question. I've lost interest in trying to help but I do wish you the best of luck.